# @Autowired is null in the class which extends Junit Testwatcher

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, junit

I am using Spring autoscan components in my testing framework.

Autowired works fine in all classes except in class which extends Junit Testwatcher.

The class where I extend Junit testwatcher is:

```
@Component
public class PrintTrace extends TestWatcher{//this class overrides pass and fail   
                                            //methods in Testwatcher           

@Autowired
private HTMLLogger htmlLogger //this is null all the time. it works in 
                              //other classes
}
```

My Base class looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:beans.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class })
public class YahooTestSetUp {

    public static WebDriver driver;


    @Rule
    public PrintTrace printTrace = new PrintTrace();



    @Autowired
    private HTMLLogger htmlLogger;//here its working fine
}
```

And my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pilz"/>
</beans>
```

Please advice this is very important for me. Otherwise I should go for 
singleton   objects,which is not a good solution for me.

---

**Adding more info:**

Lets say i have 2 test suites which access 2 common classes HTMLLogger.class and PrintTraece.class.

Each testsuite is independent of other suite. These suites have @BeforeClass and @AfterClass

**see below:**

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ AutowireClass.class})
public class YahooTestSuite extends YahooTestSetUp{
    private static HTMLLogger htmlLogger;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void allTests() throws Exception {**//Can I use @Autowired in
                                                      static methods(no)**  

        htmlLogger = new HTMlLogger()


        htmlLogger.createHTMLLogFile();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterAll() throws Exception{
        htmlLogger.htmlLogEnd();
    }


}
```

and another suite is doing same for other module.

As i said before my PrintTrace.class extends Testwatcher.class(Junit rule) its look like

This class is invoked with the the rule created in baseclass.

```
@Component
public class PrintTrace extends TestWatcher{

    private HTMLLogger htmlLogger = null;
@Override
    public void starting(final Description description) {

    }

    @Override
    public void failed(final Throwable e, final Description description) {
        htmlLogger.writeFailLog();**//This is common for all suites**
                                        //This should be same object used in suite
    }

    @Override
    public void succeeded(final Description description) {

        htmlLogger.writePassLog();//This is common for all suites
                                      //This should be same object used in suite
    }

    @Override
    public void finished(Description description) {


    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In some of the java classes, like the test cases or web-listeners, `@Autowired` doesn't work. You have to define the applicationContext like an object and receive beans manually.

```
ApplicationContext context = AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("app_context_file_path")

HTMLLogger htmlLogger = context.getBean("loggerBeanName");
```

Also, have a look over here - http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/testing.html

And google about the `@Resource` spring annotation.

To get the exact object you need, you should have the following configuration:

If you create a bean in the application context file, just use the id of it in the `getBean(name)` method. If you have it as a separate class, provide it (class) with the `@Component(value)` annotation and scan the package in the application context. After that use the value name of that bean(component) to get the exact object you've configured.

Comment: I have to use same object in different class. So how do I get it. If I load the bean manually again then there will be 2 instances. I want to use same bean across my framework.

Comment: No. It will be the same object, as you would get it via @Autowired. I will show you the way in my edit.

Comment: I am new to spring. I am confused. I have added more info under "Adding more info". Please help me where should i load beans and reuse.

Comment: I see. Well, my personal advice is to read the first chapter of the "spring in action" book - you can find it in the Internet. First of all, try to understand the IOC concept and the bean nature.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use Spring DI for JUnit rules? Your test code is not your application.

Comment: I am not using Spring DI for Junit rules but for some of my own classes. ex: HTMLLogger class. Is this what you are asking. If not please explain why shouldn't I use DI.